# Is it a convention that the distance of a vertex to itself is 1?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I was reading [this](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~jrl/421slides/lec5.pdf) file, and on the 27th page, it has a pseudo code about determining if a vertex is a articulation point in a network.

In the code, the *count* is increased before it is saved in the `d` (distance) list. So at the first the function is called, the distance of `v` to `v` is saved as one. Is it a convention in certain context/application? Because I remember in the graph definition, a vertex's distance to itself should be **zero**.

Comment: `d[v]` in that implementation of DFS is not about distance; it's about the order of discovery.

Comment: errr...ok, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

G. Bach is right, and you are right too.

In a simple graph, a vertex's distance to itself is zero.

But in some graph we called not simple, a vertex's distance to itself may vary.

The algorithm you learn is called tarjan algorithm, which is based on dfs.

Comment: "But in some graph we called not simple, a vertex's distance to itself may vary." Care to elaborate? I've never seen the distance of a vertex from itself as anything but `0`.

Comment: @G.Bach In graph theory, it does exist.

Comment: Can you give an example of formalization of non-simple graphs that is in use in some field or other where a vertex has a distance other than `0` from itself?

Comment: @G.Bach  http://www.codechef.com/AUG14/problems/REVERSE. This is an algorithm problem.   In general, you can simply define a graph that has multipal edges and self loops. It's all depends on yourself. When you doing so, the graph can't be called simple. It's just the defination